# How Can I extract & return a single value (revenue) from GA ecommerce results using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In source of the thankyou page displayed after a successful transaction on my ecommerce site Google Analytics ecommerce.js plugin writes the following :

```
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-123456789-1', {'cookieDomain': 'http://www.example.com/'});
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('send', 'pageview');


    ga('create', 'UA-1234567-9', 'auto', { name: 'merchantTracker' });
    ga('merchantTracker.require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('merchantTracker.send', 'pageview');


    Thirdparty.Event.subscribe('google.analytics.trackPageView', function(url) {
        ga('send', 'pageview', url);


        ga('merchantTracker.send', 'pageview', url);

    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.recommendation-box .in-popup a').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    window.open(
                        this.href,
                        "sharing",
                        "width=650,height=500,resizable=no,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,status=no"
                    );
                });

            ga('require', 'ecommerce');                ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
                    'id': '11377927',// Transaction ID. Required.
                    'name': 'Test Product',// Product name. Required.
                    'category': 'Adult',// Category or variation.
                    'price': '1.0000000000',// Unit price.
                    'quantity': '1'// Quantity.
                });        ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
            'id': '11377927',// Transaction ID. Required.
            'affiliation': 'My Site',// Affiliation or store name.
            'revenue': '1.070000',// Grand Total.
            'tax': '0'// Tax.
        });
        ga('ecommerce:send');
});
//]]>

</script>
```

I want to use Google Tag Manager and javascript to extract the value of 'revenue' and return that into a GTM variable.

This is on a third party platform and I do not have access to the backend source code which is why Im looking at GTM which enables me being able to use JS code on the thankyou page (I have a GTM container setup and working for other javascript on the site already)

I do not know javascript very well or the GA object model so I do not know how the best way to extract that value. I have tried, via the chrome console, to see if I can echo the value by accessing the ga object but cannot find a way to obtain it / access it.Trying such things as console.log ga('revenue') and many variations but I dont understand how the object model works to get to that value.

How can I access the value of 'revenue' and return it to GTM to use as a variable?

Comment: You need to iterate the object using custom JS. There is no direct way

Comment: Yes, Ive come to that conclusion and have had some success using innerText to confirm the value revenue is there - i am just trying to work out the correct regular expression in order to try to extract the value correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the solution to extract this using a innerText and a regex, then having obtained the index of the starting point of the value 'revenue' I used that to place the value of the number of the revenue which was starting at an index point +12 spaces ahead. 
I extracted 8 decimal points of the value as the number I will never have higher than 9999.999 usd value order and I dont require more than 3 decimal places of the value so this should be a safe range for my requirements.

I used this code in a GTM variable of custom javascript type and then included that variable in the retargeting pixel tag where required.

The console.log entries were just for testing but I have now removed from the live variable code.

```
 var content = document.head.innerText;
    var query=/'revenue': '\d+.\d+',/;
    if (content.search(query) > -1 ) {
    var resultquery = (content.search(query))
    var revenue = (document.head.innerText.substring(resultquery+12, resultquery+20))
    console.log (revenue)
    return revenue;

    } else {
      console.log(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To push values to GTM you need to first set up you dataLayer variable in GTM:

Variables -> NEW -> Choose a variable type... -> Data Layer Variable

[image]

Type your variable name and hit Save. Now you can use this variable within GTM, it will be available whereever you can and you can also reference it in your custom HTML like this: {{stackO}}
For more info: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106899?hl=en#web

To add value to this variable from your website simply push variable to GTM e.g:

dataLayer.push({
'stackO': 'exampleValue'
});

for more info: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

Unfortunately, I don't think you can access the value of 'revenue' and return it to GTM to use as a variable directly. This is becuase ga ecommerce doesn't have fucntion to return added items. (No that I know of). Ref: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

I can only advise to try to find out where that value is coming from?

'revenue': '1.070000',// Grand Total.

is it hard coded? If so maybe you can grab it directly from HTML.

Based on your comment, you can, in theory, use code like below:

```
    var x = document.head.innerText;
    var revenue=x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("'revenue'")+12,x.lastIndexOf("// Grand Total") - 2);
//assuming you name your dataLayer variable "revenue" in GTM you can push it like this:
dataLayer.push({
'revenue' : revenue
});
```

Revenue is the value you are after. But be carful, when the structure chagnes your code will stop working. Good Luck

Comment: Yes thats the problem - I cannot access the variable so need to extract the value from the html and the value changes depending on the basket total value. I did ask the third party platform but I got a non helpful reply of "that would be a custom development costing 500usd" .
Im currently trying to work out how to use  innerText to get the value - I have got code working so that it find and confirm the existence of the text "revenue" and im just trying to work out how I can then extract/return the value following that to return to the GA variable. Basically im using this so far for checking :

Comment: var content = document.head.innerText;
var query="revenue";
if (content.search(query) > -1 ) {
var result = ()
 console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}

Comment: "This is becuase ga ecommerce doesn't have fucntion to return added items." - that is helpful to know , as I was trying to find that out and was beginning to suspect the same. Thanks

Comment: there is no ga ecommerce function to return any value. This is just binding the JS object push event. What is does is getting that value from the jsb object thats it. Its not a function

Comment: I've added example of how you can return "revenue" from HTML. I hope it helps but please bare in mind it is very "dirty" solution.